# How to weight a number by quantity?

Tags: math, rating

So I'm trying to rate the best KDA (kills, deaths, assists) for individual players. The problem is each player has played the game a different number of times.

Player 1 has 9 kills, 2 deaths, and 1 assist OVER 1 game so their kda is (9+1)/2 = 5
Player 2 has 90 kills, 30 deaths, and 30 assists OVER 10 games so their kda is (90+30)/30 = 4
Player 3 has 16 kills, 8 deaths, and 20 assists OVER 5 games so their kda is (16+20)/8 = 4.5

In my mind, a KDA of **4.5 over 4 games** is better than a **KDA of 5 over 1 game**.

I'm looking for a formula to accomplish this. Initially I tried:

**games/kda+1 = SCORE**

The reason I added +1 is cause people had KDA's of <1 and that meant games/0.1 would boost their score instead of decrease it. With the +1 the denominator will always be >1.

This equation yields the following scores for the above samples:

Player 1: 0.16
Player 2: 2
Player 3: 0.909

This equation puts a too much of an emphasis on the number of games in comparison to the KDA.

Here's what I think the rankings should be like:
1. KDA 10 over 50 games
2. KDA 5 over 100 games
3. KDA 5.5 over 50 games
4. KDA 2.5 over 100 games

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** Based on Flight Odyssey's input I came up with two possible equations:
1. (GAMES*dampener1)+(KDA*dampener2) = score (add)
**OR**
2. (GAMES*dampener1)*(KDA*dampener2) = score (multiply)

Equation #2 doesn't work because that means that the score would just be adjusted by a fraction. Equation #1 means that the GAMES and KDA each have separate "adjustments" which is what I want. Then I looked at what was aiming for:

Here's what I think the rankings should be like:
1. KDA 10 over 50 games
2. KDA 5 over 100 games
3. KDA 5.5 over 50 games
4. KDA 2.5 over 100 games

I focused on scores 2 & 3 and made the KDA adjustment 10, and then varied the GAME's adjustment and compared it...

2: 50+100/x = 55+50/x then solved for X. It ended up being 10 so when the GAME'S adjuster is at 10 these two would equal each other. I adjusted that value until it "felt right" and that's what I ended up with...

(KDA * adj1) + (GAMES * adj2) = SCORE
adj1 = 10
adj2 = ?

Comment: If your formula is based on dividing by the kill death ratio, then a higher kill death ratio yields a lower score. Is that what you intended?

Comment: yea see that's another problem. Damn I really need to rework it. A high KDA and high games should #1 everything. Low kda and low games should be last. But the middle is the shaky area. A high KDA with half the games of a slightly lower KDA should be a close matchup. So based on your input it should be something like (GAMES*dampener1)+(KDA*dampener2) = score **OR** (GAMES*dampener1)*(KDA*dampener2) = score